# VBA to get open Excel Binary Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access form that opens an Excel binary file (.xlsb) from another website. I am trying to check all the user's open Excel files so that I work on the correct workbook.

By running the loop below on the opened, but not saved Excel file, the GetObject does not find the just opened workbook. This code does find other Excel files that I might already have open.

But, if I save the Excel file that I opened from the network, close and reopen it before I try to find the open Excel files with the code below, the code finds that file too.

Is there a better way for me to capture the just-opened file name? On the new Excel file, I need to filter data from particular Excel tabs and add that data to Access tables.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim strWBList As String
strWBList  = ""
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 0 Then
   Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
   For Each xlWB in xlApp.Workbooks
      If Len(strWBList) > 0 Then
         strWBList = strWBList & ","
      End If
      strWBList = strWBList & xlWB.Name
   Next xlWB
   Set xlApp = Nothing
   Set xlWB = Nothing
End If
MsgBox strWBList
```

Comment: The code you posted gives you an `Excel.Application` object, nothing more. What do you mean by *this code returns that file's information* ?

Comment: Andew- thanks for your comment, I've modified the question. I thought the reason my code was not working had something to do specifically with Excel binary files but I am not sure now.

Comment: Thanks. *I have an MS Access form that opens an Excel binary file (.xlsb)* - if your program opens the file, then this is the point where you should get a pointer to the workbook. Can you add the code that opens the file to your question?

Comment: Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName as String)

Comment: Notice you may have another `Excel.exe` running, so obviously you will not find the workbook in that app instance